# Create new data in registry key?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, registry

I just create new registry key called MyTestApp, and want to add new data in it, but don't know how.  So I have following code.

```
bool CreateSectionDataRegistry(CString sectionData, CString sectionValue)
{
    HKEY hKey;      //registry key handle
    LONG lResult;   //result of registry operations
    DWORD dwType, dwSize=0;

    //try to open the key that we are currently pointing at with rootPath
    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rootPath + "\\" + "MyTestApp", NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);

    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || lResult == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
    {
        //we have successfully opened the registry key. Now try to access the data
        lResult = RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sectionData, 0, &dwType, NULL, &dwSize); 

        if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || lResult == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        {
                          //data already exists, so just return
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
            return true;
        }
        else//section data does not exist, so create new data
        {           
            DWORD dwDisposition;
            lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sectionData, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisposition);
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
            return true;
        }   
    }

    return false;
}
```

But when I trace down to the `RegCreateKeyEx()` call, it returns success but data is not created under the MyTestApp registry key or anywhere in the registry.  Am I using the correct function to create new data under MyTestApp.  Also from the argument above, I have `CString` sectionValue, so how do I check if I need to create data for `REG_SZ` or `REG_DWORD`?

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably by `windows-mobile` you mean pre-7, right?

Comment: You meant the tagged, it's for handheld device either WinCE or Windows Mobile.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Just checking. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just need to call RegSetValueEx() to create registry value under MyTestApp.  Probably just me but when I look at the RegSetValueEx() definition in Microsoft website, it says set the value, but it does not say if value does not exist, it will create the value.

```
LPTSTR lpszData = new TCHAR[sectionValue.GetLength() + 1];
_tcscpy(lpszData, sectionValue);
lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, sectionData, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)lpszData, sectionValue.GetLength());
```

So now it creates the registry value, however I cannot still tell if sectionValue is REG_SZ or REG_DWORD.

Comment: The RegSetValueEx function will create values if they do not exist and overwrite old ones if they do. You set the data type to REG_SZ, so that's the type that gets recorded into the registry. When you read back your value, it will return the data type as REG_SZ since that's how you marked it.